# Higher-order function accepting function with arbitrary number of parameters

Tags: f#, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

Is there a way in F# to write a higher-order function capable of accepting curried functions with arbitrary number of parameters? For example, how do I write a single `lift` function working with both `f : x:int -> int` and `g : x:int -> y:int -> int`?

```
let f x = x + 1
let g x y = x + y

let lift1 s f x = (f x, s)
let lift2 s f x y = (f x y, s)

let fLifted = lift1 "Func f" f
let gLifted = lift2 "Func g" g
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this can't be done without tricky extra operators. (leaving you with something like `lift a <|> b <|> c`)

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more about it? In your example you have three values `a`, `b`, and `c` entering the expression but I would like to pass just `f` and `s`. Also, any pointer to how the operator `<|>` is defined would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't actually know the answer in this case, but these sorts of questions can usually be answered in this sort of way.  The easiest way is probably to make `<|>` behave in a similar (but different) way to `::` and you create a list that way.  A better example would have been something `lift s f x <|> y <|> z <|>`.  I had just missed the other parameters

Comment: Thank you, John. It looks like I have to de-curry the function somehow making it a single-parameter function of some heterogeneous list of original parameters.